# Does not consume 1 consonant after set of vowels?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

This is a script which will display substring containing only vowels of length greater than 2 between 2 consonants.

```
import re
v = "aeiou"
c = "qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm"
m = re.findall(r"(?<=[%s])([%s]{2,})[%s]" % (c, v, c), input(), flags = re.I)
print('\n'.join(m or ['-1']))
```

It works perfectly, but I just can't understand.Why it does not consume 1 consonant after set of vowels?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because `[%s]` is not enclosed in `(`,`)` brackets:

> (...)    Matches the RE inside the parentheses.
>              The contents can be retrieved or matched later in the string.

Though doing `(?<=[%s])([%s]{2,})([%s])` for `qaer` gives `m=[('ae','r')]`.

Comment: what is the use of [%s] here

Comment: @kunal `%s` stands from string same as in `C,C++,Java`,etc. here %s is being replaced by c,v and c respectively

Comment: i know that but i want to know what its role in above regex.

Comment: `r"(?<=[%s])([%s]{2,})[%s]" % (c, v, c)` is same as `r"(?<=[qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm)([aeiou]{2,})[qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm]"`